# How to read a BufferedReader twice or multiple times?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a text file with one integer per row -

```
10
20
50
```

I want to read and print these numbers twice or maybe even multiple times. I tried some code and it failed. How do I change my code to print the list twice ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DoubleBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:/files/numbers.txt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;

                // Read rows
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                }   

                // Read rows again
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                }

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }//try-catch

    }// main

}// class
```

Comment: Either store them in a list or restart the buffer/

Comment: If 'memory is not an issue' you might store the entire input as a `byte[]` then create a `ByteArrayInpuStream` as needed.

Comment: Storing them on a list would be ideal.

Comment: @ChristianMark - yes makes sense. Re-reading the file would require twice the IO. Also, we need to use the same memory twice to store the rows as we read them. Right ???

Comment: Please do not use DataInputStream to read text, also please remove it from your example and this bad idea is copied often. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can print multiple times.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "D:/log_2071-04-31.txt" ));
String strLine;
ArrayList<String> ans= new ArrayList<String>();

// Read rows
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(strLine);
    ans.add(strLine);
}

// Read again
for (String result: ans) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: yes makes sense. Re-reading the file would require twice the IO.

Comment: Please do not use DataInputStream to read text, also please remove it from your example and this bad idea is copied often. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: Ganesh - please read what Berryllium said below. "a data structure is in the heap memory, and if you have large files, you could run into an OutOfMemoryError. If your application was multi-threaded, this problem could emerge even sooner. If you use a data structure, you have imposed a limit on the file size"

Comment: I am not sure this answer should be made a community wiki. The solution will work well for me because of the small size of my files.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mark()` and `reset()` or just open the file again. Depending on your use, perhaps you want to store the data in memory?

Reference - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#reset%28%29

Comment: Can you show me how to use mark and reset here? Also, how do I open the file again ? Do I have to use this code to re-open the file - FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream("c:/files/numbers.txt"); ?

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility: Attach listeners to a `MultiReader`.

```
interface Listener {
    void read(String line);
}

class MultiReader {
    final List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener l) {
        this.listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void read(File file) throws IOException {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
        String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (Listener l : this.listeners) {
                    l.read(line);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

to be used like this:

```
public class MultiBufferedReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MultiReader mr = new MultiReader();

        mr.addListener(new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void read(String line) {
                System.out.println("1: Got " + line);
            }
        });

        mr.addListener(new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void read(String line) {
                System.out.println("2: Got " + line);
            }
        });

        mr.read(new File("/etc/hosts"));
    }
```

So the file is read once, and it can handle large files, because the file's content is not held in memory.

Comment: Thanks. But it looks so complicated to me. Is there any advantage of using this method over a data structure ?

Comment: @Use your head It can handle large files. Whereas a data structure is in the heap memory, and if you have large files, you could run into an `OutOfMemoryError`. If your application was multi-threaded, this problem could emerge even sooner. If you use a data structure, you have imposed a limit on the file size.

Comment: As for its complexity: It's the same pattern, if you attach an `ActionListener` to a `JButton` - it's a callback. It's likely that you can use/find this pattern in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class DoubleBuffer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:/files/numbers.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;

            // Read rows
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strLine);
            }   
            // return stream to top of file
            fstream.getChannel().position(0);
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));


            // Read rows again
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strLine);
            }

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }//try-catch

}// main

 }// class
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading same stuff multiple times will lead to poor performance... 
Unless you have a very strong reason to make multiple reads,  read at the beginning of main method and store the data in a suitable data structure for your requirement.