# Where will bufferreader refer to if I call it twice

Tags: java, string, api, while-loop, filereader

I search the content in a file line by line using a while loop until I find the String 'MATCH'. 
But when in another function I need to use BufferReader again, will it refer to the end of file or start from the very beginning of the file?

```
Public String method1(String match){
  String line;
  while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null){
  if (line = match)
  return line;
  }
}
```

Public String method2.......

When implementing method 2, will bufferReader point to the place when line = match? Or bufferReader will be re-initialised to the beginning of the file?

Comment: Your if syntax is wrong (it needs == ), please correct that.

Comment: Take a closer look at `=` & `==`. Never compare String in Java with `==` instead use `equals()` method of `Object` class.

Comment: Have a look at these post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269329/how-to-read-a-bufferedreader-twice-or-multiple-times & http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/123200/sharing-buffer-between-multiple-threads

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the BufferedReader is "shared" among all places where it's used. If you read lines until you reach a `"MATCH"`, and use the BufferedReader in another method, it will continue from that line.

Also,

```
if (line = match)
```

doesn't look right. You're probably after

```
if (line.equals(match))
```

Comment: Is there a method to initialise BufferedReader?

Comment: To reset it to read from the beginning again? No, you could try this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034311/multiple-readers-for-inputstream-in-java

Comment: If I closed FileReader, will the BufferedReader read from the beginning again?

Comment: If you close the underlying FileReader you will no be able to use the BufferedReader. Why don't you simply recreate a new buffered reader / file reader if you want to start over from the beginning?